# NoSQL with key/value/value

Tags: java, nosql

I'm looking for a NoSQL database with the simplicity and speed of [kyoto cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) that allows me to store 2 values per key. Also with a Java API.
I looked at http://nosql-database.org/ but am a bit overwhelmed by the number of choices so I was hoping that people here could advise me (preferrably open source as my application will be open source as well).

What I'm trying to achieve is: store a data-"value" + a count-value with a hash-key.
To elaborate:

- I have a table with an index-value (0...infinite) where each index maps to a hash. multiple indexes can map to the same hash
- then I have a table where the key (that same hash as the index-table) maps to a blob of data
- now to determine if I can throw away the hash/data pair, I need to determine how many index-values map to a hash. as iterating through the index/hash-table takes too long (millions of records and kyoto cabinet has no direct commands for doing so), I now have a seperate table where each hash maps to a value indicating the use-count
- I would like to store this count in the hash/data-table to prevent another look-up (which cause a diskseek)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you want to make complex key (like `"my_key_1_count_10"`) and store into key/value database ?

Comment: because I need to update that count-field often as index/hash-pairs are often added and removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x69's idea point me in the right direction.

Now my hash + count and hash + data are in the same table, but the hash for count is prefixed with 'c' and the data-one with a 'd'.

This method enabled me to use kyoto cabinet for it. KC has transaction-support which takes away all the hassle of implementing journalling myself.